# Force UI redraw after loading new resource files

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, xaml

I have defined 2 themes (Resource files containing colours - .xaml), one in the resource dictionary on app load and one added on a button click by the following code:

```
 Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear()
        Dim lightTheme As New ResourceDictionary()
        Dim lightThemeUri As New Uri("/MyApp.UI;component/Assets/ColourResourcesLight.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
        lightTheme.Source = lightThemeUri
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(lightTheme)
```

The colours in the new light theme are defined with the same key as the dark theme (loaded when app loads). My controls are then bound to this key with a staticResource.

After the new resource file loads i would like to somehow update / force a redraw of the whole UI to allow my new theme to display. This works on the controls contained in pages that i then navigate to, however it does not update my navigation bar (Main Page). Every other page is loaded into a container on the main page.

I would like the navigation bar to also update.

Was wondering what the best way to do this was, i have tried updating the bindings by using :

```
 Public Shared Sub ForceControlRebind(cntrl As Control, depprop As DependencyProperty)
    Try
        Dim BindExp As BindingExpression = cntrl.GetBindingExpression(depprop)
        Dim Bind As Binding = BindExp.ParentBinding
        cntrl.SetBinding(depprop, Bind)
    Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

However the BindExp always returns nothing.

I have also tried forcing a UI redraw by using:

```
mainpage.InvalidateMeasure()
mainpage.InvalidateArrange()
mainpage.UpdateLayout()
```

I know the resource file is properly loaded as the properties have updated when i step into the controls